# How To Store Foreign Key With Different Tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with my script

This is My Code.

**1. DataIndustri Migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('data_industri', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nama_perusahaan')->nullable();
            $table->string('pemilik_perusahaan')->nullable();
            $table->string('kategori_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('alamat_perusahaan')->nullable();
            $table->string('kecamatan_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('klbi')->nullable();
            $table->string('slug')->nullable();
            $table->string('gambar')->nullable();
            $table->integer('nilai_investasi')->nullable();
            $table->integer('jml_tenaga_kerja')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**2. DataIndustriModel**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DataIndustriModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'data_industri';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_perusahaan',
        'pemilik_perusahaan',
        'alamat_perusahaan',
        'kategori_id',
        'kecamatan_id',
        'nilai_investasi',
        'jml_tenaga_kerja',
        'koordinat',
        'slug',
        'gambar',
    ];

    public function kategoris()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(KategoriIndustriModel::class, 'kategori_id', 'id');
    }
    
    public function kecamatans()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(KecamatanModel::class, 'kecamatan_id', 'id');
    }
    
    public function produk_industris()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProdukIndustriModel::class, 'nama_perusahaan_id', 'id' );
    }
}
```

3. **produk_industri migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produk_industri', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('nama_perusahaan_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('nama_perusahaan_id')->references('id')
            ->on('data_industri');
            $table->string('komoditi')->nullable();
            $table->integer('kapasitas_komoditi')->nullable();
            $table->string('satuan_komoditi')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**4. DataProdukIndustriModel**

```
class ProdukIndustriModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_perusahaan_id',
        'produk_industri_id',
        'komoditi',
        'kapasitas_komoditi',
        'satuan_komoditi',
    ];
}
```

and this is my controller

**5. StoreController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
    
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nama_perusahaan'                   => 'required',
            'pemilik_perusahaan'                => 'required',
            'alamat'                            => 'required',
            'kecamatan'                         => 'required',
            'kategori'                          => 'required',
            'nilai_investasi'                   => 'required',
            'jml_tenaga_kerja'                  => 'required',
            'koordinat'                         => 'required',
            'klbi'                              => 'required',
            'komoditi'                          => 'required',
            'satuan_komoditi'                   => 'required',
            'kapasitas_komoditi'                => 'required',
            'gambar'                            => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ],[
            'nama_perusahaan.required'          => 'Nama Perusahaan Mohon Diisi',
            'pemilik_perusahaan.required'       => 'Pemilik Perusahaan Mohon Diisi',
            'alamat.required'                   => 'Alamat Perusahaan Mohon Diisi',
            'kecamatan.required'                => 'Kecematan Mohon Dipilih',
            'kategori.required'                 => 'Kategori Perusahaan Mohon Dipilih',
            'nilai_investasi.required'          => 'Nilai Investasi Mohon Diisi',
            'jml_tenaga_kerja.required'         => 'Jumlah Tenaga Kerja Mohon Diisi',
            'koordinat.required'                => 'Lokasi Koordinat Mohon Diisi',
            'klbi.required'                     => 'Kode KLBI Mohon Diisi',
            'komoditi.required'                 => 'Jenis Komoditas Belum Diisi',
            'satuan_komoditi.required'          => 'Satuan Komoditas Belum Diisi',
            'kapasitas_komoditi.required'       => 'Kapasitas Komoditas Belum Diisi',
            'gambar.required'                   => 'Ukuran Maksimal Gambar 2MB dan Format JPEG, JPG, PNG, GIF'
        ]
      );
        $data1 = $request->all();
        $data1['nama_perusahaan']               = $request->nama_perusahaan;
        $data1['slug']                          = Str::slug($request->nama_perusahaan);
        $data1['pemilik_perusahaan']            = $request->pemilik_perusahaan;
        $data1['alamat_perusahaan']             = $request->alamat;
        $data1['kecamatan_id']                  = $request->kecamatan;
        $data1['kategori_id']                   = $request->kategori;
        $data1['nilai_investasi']               = $request->nilai_investasi;
        $data1['jml_tenaga_kerja']              = $request->jml_tenaga_kerja;
        $data1['koordinat']                     = $request->koordinat;
        $data1['gambar']                        = $request->file('gambar')->store('industri','public');

        $data2 = $request->all();
        $data2['nama_perusahaan_id']            = {{ ????????? }}
        $data2['klbi']                          = $request->klbi;
        $data2['komoditi']                      = $request->komoditi;
        $data2['satuan_komoditi']               = $request->satuan_komoditi;
        $data2['kapasitas_komoditi']            = $request->kapasitas_komoditi;
    
        DataIndustriModel::create($data1);
        ProdukIndustriModel::create($data2);
        FacadesAlert::success('Berhasil', 'Data Berhasil Tersimpan');
        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
```

My question is, how to store **nama_perusahaan_id** as **foreign key** in Tabel **produk_industri** where the value is from **id** in tabel **data_industri**

Thanks in advance ..

i hope someone could help me with my script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should store **DataIndustriModel::create($data1)** to a variable and after that you can get the nama_perusahaan_id.

```
$data1 = $request->all();
$data1["nama_perusahaan"] = $request->nama_perusahaan;
$data1["slug"] = Str::slug($request->nama_perusahaan);
$data1["pemilik_perusahaan"] = $request->pemilik_perusahaan;
$data1["alamat_perusahaan"] = $request->alamat;
$data1["kecamatan_id"] = $request->kecamatan;
$data1["kategori_id"] = $request->kategori;
$data1["nilai_investasi"] = $request->nilai_investasi;
$data1["jml_tenaga_kerja"] = $request->jml_tenaga_kerja;
$data1["koordinat"] = $request->koordinat;
$data1["gambar"] = $request->file("gambar")->store("industri", "public");

$data1 = DataIndustriModel::create($data1);
```

After that you can get **nama_perusahaan_id** using **$data1->id**

```
$data2 = $request->all();
$data2['nama_perusahaan_id'] = $data1->id;
$data2['klbi'] = $request->klbi;
$data2['komoditi'] = $request->komoditi;
$data2['satuan_komoditi'] = $request->satuan_komoditi;
$data2['kapasitas_komoditi'] = $request->kapasitas_komoditi;
ProdukIndustriModel::create($data2);
```

You can read the documentation from [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserts)